# SVG to make a wave effect border and allow it to stretch horizontally only

Tags: html, css, svg

I have used https://getwaves.io/ to create a wave SVG.

So I have added this svg to my header element:

```css
.page{
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    background: green;
}
.pls-sticky-header{
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}
.wave{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

````html
<div class="page">
<div class="pls-sticky-header">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1440 200" class="wave">
        <path fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L40,117.3C80,107,160,85,240,90.7C320,96,400,128,480,154.7C560,181,640,203,720,192C800,181,880,139,960,106.7C1040,75,1120,53,1200,58.7C1280,64,1360,96,1400,112L1440,128L1440,320L1400,320C1360,320,1280,320,1200,320C1120,320,1040,320,960,320C880,320,800,320,720,320C640,320,560,320,480,320C400,320,320,320,240,320C160,320,80,320,40,320L0,320Z"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
</div>

```
````

Currently as the window gets larger in size - waves get more space in height - but I don't want such behavior.

**I want to make waves get 30% of the header in height, and 100% of width (make them stretch only horizontally), but I'm struggling with it.**
Maybe there is an option to make such border for a DIV vlock if it not possible to achieve using SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

```css
.page {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.pls-sticky-header {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.wave {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height:30%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="pls-sticky-header">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1440 200" class="wave" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L40,117.3C80,107,160,85,240,90.7C320,96,400,128,480,154.7C560,181,640,203,720,192C800,181,880,139,960,106.7C1040,75,1120,53,1200,58.7C1280,64,1360,96,1400,112L1440,128L1440,320L1400,320C1360,320,1280,320,1200,320C1120,320,1040,320,960,320C880,320,800,320,720,320C640,320,560,320,480,320C400,320,320,320,240,320C160,320,80,320,40,320L0,320Z"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: You are my hero. Couldn't find such simple property...

Answer (score 0):

You can give a height attribute to the svg. Right now it is modifying the height to match the width. Don't use percentages for the height. because it will change with screen size.

Comment: then it will "cut" the svg not resize it

Comment: If you give the .wave class a height of %100 doesn't it take the height of the 150px container?